# Strange issue - Facebook birthdays not syncing now

Tags: iphone, facebook, synchronization

I don't understand what went wrong suddenly with my application.I was able to implement user login,fetch friend details like name,birthday,picture etc. and was even able to sync the same and save those details in to my database.But to my surprise after several runs of my application,I ran in to an crash issue with simulator and could see below log in console:

**Couldn't register com.myApp.debug with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code. This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Program received signal: “SIGABRT”.**

I have searched for solutions and found out in some post on stack over flow that 'If restarting simulator and xcode not fixing your issue,you need to restart your mac as it worked perfect for me with xcode 4.2/4.3' and that worked like a magic in my case too!

But what happened now when I ran the application was when I click the Facebook button,it navigates the user to permission and authorization page,as I have already authorized my application,it displays the message 'Your app is already authorized,Click Ok to continue'.

**Issue:** When I click 'Ok' button it navigated to my Sync Settings page earlier,but now it is quitting from the application and entering background.When I select the application it is taking me to sync settings page,but when I click on 'Sync' button,earlier the details of friends were synced and saved to db,but now I could see HTTP error message in log,i.e.:

**Error: HTTP status code: 400**

I googled for solutions but in vain,found a few posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178962/iphone-app-crashes-after-first-facebook-connect-authorization-login?rq=1) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805743/facebook-sdk-3-1-error-http-status-code-400/13415309#13415309) ,which were helpless.

**Note: I am using the Facebook 3.0 SDK,as of now I am working on Xcode 4.2,I am not using the Facebook latest version of SDK i.e. 3.2 as I heard it requires Xcode version of 4.5 and above.There is another constraint over there for me to download Xcode 4.5 as it requires Mac os x 17.1 and above,but my current version is Mac os x 16.8 Snow Leapord.There is a way to upgrade I do agree,but as of now I have no time to do all the stuff,I need to wrap up my application.**

Hence if any one is familiar with Facebook SDK 3.0,please help me get out of this!

Assistance needed.Thanks all in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution to my problem,I have found another instance of my application which was already hung in simulator,when I deleted it,everything worked fine.

Hope it helps some one,thanks :)